# process_orders_on_close is giving an error

Tags: pine-script

I'm getting the error below when I add the `process_orders_on_close` argument.
If I remove it, the script runs fine. Please help.

```
strategy("MATESTHL2", process_orders_on_close = true, shorttitle="MATESTHL2", overlay=true, initial_capital=100000, pyramiding=1, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100)
```

*line 2: Cannot call `strategy` with arguments (literal string, process_orders_on_close=literal bool, shorttitle=literal string, overlay=literal bool, initial_capital=literal integer, pyramiding=literal integer, default_qty_type=const string, default_qty_value=literal integer);

available overloads: strategy(const string, const string, const bool, const integer, const integer, const integer, const bool, const bool, const integer, const integer, const string, const float, const float, const string, const bool, const bool, const string, const integer, const string, const float, const string, const string) => void*

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to add the `//@version=4` tag.
This works on my end:

```
//@version=4
strategy("MATESTHL2", process_orders_on_close = true, shorttitle="MATESTHL2", overlay=true, initial_capital=100000, pyramiding=1, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100)
```